# flash mp3 player for web

Tags: php, flash

I am building a php-based website. I want when the main page loads, then play a random song from a folder of songs. there should be a play, pause, stop control for the song. a flash player would do that. but i cannot find a suitable one. can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many utilities available to do this. One of the more popular ones (that I  have used before) is [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). It has a [large set of features](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-player/features/) and even has a [wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=202) to help with setup. Additionally, it is beginning to support HTML5 (assuming you are playing an HTML5-compatible file and your client is using a browser that supports HTML5 - otherwise, it will fall back to Flash).

Just a note: This player is free (and open-source, as far as I can remember), but the licensing can be odd (for example, use on commercial websites *might* require payment).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

It does html5 audio tags, with a fallback to a flash player when those are available.

Answer (score 0):

Try JWPlayer  or flowplayer.
JWPlayer is free to use, but commercial use requires some expensive licensing.
FlowPlayer is completely free.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/

http://www.flowplayer.org